# ToString() returns null?

Tags: .net, nullreferenceexception, tostring

I am trying to determine cause of 'Null reference exception' on published remote site. So, I can't debug it directly and can operate only with logs. So my question is:
Is it possible, that `.ToString()` method of any of built-in .NET types returns `null`?

**EDIT:**
I suspect `DateTime.ToString(invariantCulture)` method with badly constructed culture settings.

Comment: It's more likely that the object you're calling .ToString() on is null. Do you have the possibility to view the stacktrace, and find the relevant piece of code?

Comment: If it's using the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, it shouldn't fail. If it's badly formed CultureInfo, it'll give a CultureNotFoundException.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any types where it does. It's not impossible - it would certainly be easy to write your own type which behaved like that - but I *doubt* any of the framework types do.

Do you have any particular types in mind?

EDIT: `DateTime.ToString(invariantCulture)` should *never* return null - the culture settings should be irrelevant, if you've *really* got the invariant culture.

Comment: Since all(?) framework types (and all types) inherit from System.Object, and the Object.ToString() method simply returns the type name... wouldn't it actually be impossible? Unless, of course, someone's overridden ToString() to return null in some bizarre case...

Comment: @J. Steen: Someone overriding `ToString` in a way which returns null in some situations is exactly what I was considering.

Answer (score -2):

You can also override the `ToString()` method and assign it a custom value. If it returns null still, then the object is null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: No method can be called on a null object. If you try to call `ToString()` on a null object it will throw a `NullReferenceException`. The conclusion “if it returns null still then the object is null” is not possible and thus **wrong**. The provided link seems to be dead and thus is not helpful for original context.

Comment: He asked if any object in .NET can return null. I answered saying if he overrides it and returns null in the string, it returns null. Sorry if I wasn’t clear, but it most certainly isn’t wrong. OP didn’t ask if calling ToString on a null throws an exception, he asked can it return null.

Comment: Also after 9 years links are likely to be stale when posts are resurrected from the grave.

Comment: That’s why StackOverflow guidelines suggest making answers self-sufficient, and replicating the relevant parts of the linked to content. The link in this answer is neither labeled nor given context on what it is for/attempts to reference or explain specifically.