# How to find if an element of a list is in another list and the name of element?

Tags: c#, performance

First I want to know if at least one element in a first list can be found in a second list.

```
List<string> list1 = new[] { "A", "C", "F", "H", "I" };
List<string> list2 = new[] { "B", "D", "F", "G", "L" };
```

I am using below code to do this -

```
bool isFound = list1.Intersect(list2).Any();
```

But I want to know which element is that. Like in above case it is `'F'`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: list1.Intersect(list2) gives you the intersecting elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
        List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "A", "C", "F", "H", "I" };
        List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "B", "D", "F", "G", "L" };
        String sel = list1.Intersect(list2).FirstOrDefault()??"";

        Console.WriteLine(sel);
```

Try my [Demo](http://ideone.com/G2js8c)

Comment: `ToString()` is very [unlikly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815187/tostring-returns-null) to return `null` I would sugges: `list1.Intersect(list2).FirstOrDefault()??""` instead

Comment: Sorry i forgot to remove the ToString(). Thanks for that one @JensKloster.

Answer (score 4):

You just use `Intersect` only:

```
var result = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302032.aspx) method only, you don't need to use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) in your case.

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>(){ "A", "C", "F", "H", "I" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>(){ "B", "D", "F", "G", "L" };

var intersect = list1.Intersect(list2);

foreach (var i in intersect)
{
     Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Output will be;

```
F
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/q6c9It).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of bool variable You can take another list variable like:

`List<string> list3` Variable to get list of items which are forund in second list and assign the result to list3

```
 List<string> list3= list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

Comment: `Any` returns a `bool`value. you cant assign it to a list

Comment: ok it can be:`List<string> list3= list1.Intersect(list2).toList();`